# Can I configure a Kotlin Multiplatform module in a Gradle plugin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm building a project with several `Kotlin Multiplatform` modules.
As the `Gradle` [documentation suggests](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html), to share configuration between those modules I've created a custom plugin. This plugin is supposed to apply the `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin and the shared configuration but unfortunately it's unable to resolve the `kotlin` extension for applying the multiplatform configuration.

My plugin (`buildSrc\src\main\kotlin\my.pugin.gradle.kts`):

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
    }

    jvm {
        val main by compilations.getting {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
> public fun DependencyHandler.kotlin(module: String, version: String? = ...): Any defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl
> public fun PluginDependenciesSpec.kotlin(module: String): PluginDependencySpec defined in org.gradle.kotlin.dsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, what you need is to add a dependency of the `buildSrc` on the `kotlin-gradle-plugin` in `buildSrc\build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
    //...
}
```

**EDIT:** `$kotlin_version` is unavailable at this scope, you need to specify it explicitly.